# What do I need to monitor on a couple of servers?

Tags: monitoring

I have an internal lab I need to monitor, but I want to make sure that I'm monitoring the right stuff (this is my first crack at operational management). Right now I have the following servers to monitor:

- Web Servers (IIS)
- Database server (SQL - OLTP)
- Data warehouse server (SQL - OLAP)

Plus 3 servers that actually generate load during load tests.

Currently I'm just monitoring for disk space usage and am getting alerts if any logical disk falls below 10% free space. None of these machines are production, they're all in a testing lab, so 24/7 uptime isn't required and we don't have someone on call to fix the machines. Mainly we just want a way to know if a disk is about to fail, if we're running out of space during the day (due to database bloat during a test or whatever), and anything I'm not really considering (do I need to monitor network traffic, for example?)

For the purposes of this question, assume I'm just running Perfmon and am picking out the counters manually.

Answer (score 1):

PhysicalDisk - Average Queue Length is always a good one to watch, this could indicate a number of things: performance is low, disk failure imminent, need more memory, need more spindles, etc.

Comment: That's a good point. Tracking that on physical rather than logical makes a lot of sense for the operational monitoring aspect, thanks! Would there be any sort of industry threshold on this number, or is it dependent on what my baselines are?

Comment: Yes, it does depend on your baselines, but largely I take action when it is persistently over 2 (or, on slow/old machines, over 5-10) for prolonged periods. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722466.aspx for a bit of Microsoft blurb on the matter. :)